# Async Ajax vs Async attribute

Tags: html, ajax, asynchronous

just a quick question is the async Ajax the same as the async attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very broad terms: yes. However, since one applies to XHR requests and the other to script elements, there isn't much point in trying to lump them together.